# OPenMP loop increment

Tags: c++, c, openmp

Is it OK to use loop increment greater than 1?

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic, 1000)
for (int i=0; i<100000; i+=10)
{
    // do something that uses i
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you think it should be a problem?

Comment: I found a problem with non-1 increments here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77385488/clang-openmp-loop-continues-counting-beyond-loop-condition-limit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

The allowed form for the for loop is:

```
for (init-expr; test-expr; incr-expr) structured-block
```

Where incr_expr is any of:

```
++var
var++
--var
var--
var += incr
var -= incr
var = var + incr
var = incr + var
var = var - incr
```

See http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/OpenMP3.1.pdf page 40.

Answer (score 3):

Another way of thinking of it is:

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic, 1000)
for (int i=0; i<100000; i+=10)
{
    // do something that uses i
}
```

Could be rewritten as

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic, 1000)
for (int j=0; j<10000; j++)
{
    i = 10*j;
    // do something that uses i
}
```