# clang OpenMP loop continues counting beyond loop condition limit

Tags: clang, openmp, clang++

I have the following interesting problem:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>

using namespace std;

int main(const int, const char **) {

  const size_t n = 13; // triggers the issue
  // const uint32_t n = 13; // fixes the issue

#pragma omp parallel for
  for (uint32_t i = 0; i < n; i += 2) { // `+= 1` fixes the issue
    cerr << "i = " << i << ", n = " << n << endl;
  }

}
```

Despite my `i < n`, where `n = 13` this prints an infinite series of numbers on `clang++ -fopenmp`:

```
i = 0, n = 13
i = 2, n = 13
i = 4, n = 13
i = 6, n = 13
i = 8, n = 13
i = 10, n = 13
i = 12, n = 13     <- this should be impossible
i = 14, n = 13
...
```

How can this be?

This happens with clang++ 11, 14, and 16, but not with GCC. It's also fixed if `-fopenmp` is removed.

The issue dissappears if I do `+= 1` instead of `+= 2`.

According to [OPenMP loop increment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7448812/openmp-loop-increment), a "loop increment greater than 1" is legal.

The issue also disappears if I change the type of `n` from `size_t` to `uint32_t`.

### Observation regarding warnings

With `-Wall` and `+= 2`, `clang++` prints these warnings:

```
clang-openmp-for-loop-test.cpp:49:3: warning: implicit conversion from 'unsigned long' to 'unsigned int' changes value from 9223372034707292167 to 2147483655 [-Wconstant-conversion]
  for (uint32_t i = 0; i < n; i += 2) {
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
clang-openmp-for-loop-test.cpp:49:3: warning: implicit conversion from 'unsigned long' to 'unsigned int' changes value from 9223372034707292167 to 2147483655 [-Wconstant-conversion]
  for (uint32_t i = 0; i < n; i += 2) {
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
clang-openmp-for-loop-test.cpp:49:3: warning: implicit conversion from 'unsigned long' to 'unsigned int' changes value from 9223372034707292167 to 2147483655 [-Wconstant-conversion]
  for (uint32_t i = 0; i < n; i += 2) {
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
3 warnings generated.
```

There are multiple things I don't understand about these warnings:

1. Why is the same warning (at same code position) emitted 3 times?
2. Where is the value `9223372034707292167` coming from? It's a `-Wconstant-conversion` warning, surely it should warn about some constants I actually use. The value `2147483655` is the `maximum 32-bit-signed integer + 8`.
3. How comes this type-related warning goes away when I change `+= 2` to `+= 1`? Surely the *type* of those two literals are the same?

### Environment

Ubuntu 22.04.

```bash
sudo apt install clang14 libomp-14-dev gcc+12 libstdc++-12-dev
```

(The `gcc+12 libstdc++-12-dev` are needed just for `#include <iostream>` to work, as clang uses GCC's stdlib headers.)

Compile:

```bash
clang++ myprogram.cpp -o myprogram -fopenmp -O2 -Wall -Wextra
```

Run:

```bash
OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 ./myprogram 2>&1 | head -n20
```

---

Compiler bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: You're mixing signed and unsigned quantities. For instance, your stopping test and increment have integer quantities. What happens if you make everything signed?

Comment: @VictorEijkhout The stopping test is not signed: Both `size_t` and `uint32_t` are unsigned. The warnings also mention no signed quantities. Your tip with the increment is still good: Changing `+= 2` to `2lu` or `2llu` fixes the bug, but oddly `2u` does NOT fix the bug. So it cannot be just the signedness of the incerment.

Answer (score 3):

Changint the test to an explicit cast `i < (uint32_t)n` fixes the problem with clang (17).

But the explicit cast `(size_t)i < n` results in a compilation error:

`condition of OpenMP for loop must be a relational comparison ('<', '<=', '>', '>=', or '!=') of loop variable 'i'`.

It's not really clear to me, but my understanding of the OpenMP 5.2 specification (the latest one, but I don't which one clang uses) is that the test expression of a C/C++ OpenMP loop shall involve the variable `i` alone either on the lhs or on the rhs (page 88 of the [specification](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMP-API-Specification-5-2.pdf)):

[image]

Because `i` and `n` are of different types the compiler has to implicitely cast one of them, and because `n` has the wider range, this is `i` that is cast. Then the test does no longer involve `i` alone but a function of `i`.

So, the initial problem is probably that this is an illegal OpenMP code, even if gcc handles it as an extension to the OpenMP specification. Still, this is also a clang compiler error: clang initially goes to the implicit cast route, and then messes up the loop (it should either produce a compilation error because of the illegal code, or handle it correctly as an extension like gcc does).

Comment: Thank you, I've filed a clang bug at: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/70687